# Ubuntu Server Postfix no main.cf file?

Tags: server, postfix

I've elected to install a local Ubuntu 16.04 server at my house. Part of this install appears to have postfix installed (I attempted to do `apt-get install postfix` and it said I already had the newest version.

My next goal was to configure it to use SendGrid to relay the messages. However, to do that, I need to modify the postfix `main.cf` file. I don't have a `main.cf` file in `/etc/postfix`.

I have a `main.cf.proto`. None of the information I've found in how to set up postfix mentions this file. They all assume that `main.cf` exists.

Do I copy `main.cf.proto` to `main.cf`? Or should I be finding another file and my install is messed up in some way?

Comment: Does `main.cf` appear after you do `sudo dpkg-reconfigure postfix`?

Answer (score 1):

Run the following commands:

```
apt-get purge postfix
apt-get install postfix
```

The configuration wizard will recreate this file if you will choose anything besides no configuration

Comment: You missing the "&&" symbol between two queries ``apt-get purge postfix && apt-get install postfix``

Comment: @SailabRahi actually the user had those two as separate lines but didn't know that SE combines lines unless you use two `ENTER` commands, or use <br>, or use a `code` block.